# How to implement a simple button in PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, button, pyqt, signals-slots

I want to implement a simple button in PyQt which prints "Hello world" when clicked. How can I do that?

I am a real newbie in PyQt.

Comment: Try to read some [tutorials](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're new to PyQt, there are some useful tutorials on the [PyQt Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) to get you started. But in the meantime, here's your "Hello World" example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        print('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When I try this I get: `Failed to load platform plugin "xcb". Available platforms are "linuxfb" and "minimal". Do you know why? I am running from with the latest stable Python, IPython, Qt5 and snapshot from PyQt4`

Comment: @user815423426. Sounds like your installation is broken. What platform are you on, and how did you install the components?