# extracting python exe created via Iexpress getting ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Error

Tags: pyqt, iexpress

I build one code and then created a exe from .py using py2exe .

Now i want to create a self expracted for the same so i used Iexpress to do that . I am able to create the exe from Iexpress but when i try to extract my application from the exe created i get following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C.py", line 44, in <module>
File "A.pyc", line 4, in <module>
File "PyQt4\QtGui.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "PyQt4\QtGui.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It seems , error is all coming in line :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

I saw some ways to fix this on internet but couldnt succeed to fix this . Anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this here, but it seems to work fine. Here's what I did:

1. Created a file `hello-pyqt.py` using this question:
   [How to implement a simple button in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762870/how-to-implement-a-simple-button-in-pyqt)
2. Created a `setup.py`:

   ```
   from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe

   setup(console=['hello-pyqt.py'],
         options={'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,
                             'dll_excludes': ['w9xpopen.exe', 'MSVCP90.dll'],
                             'includes': ['sip']}}
        )
   ```

   The `dll_excludes` and `includes` tricks came from an answer on [py2exe fails to generate an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323424/py2exe-fails-to-generate-an-executable/774715#774715) and this [Py2exeAndPyQt page](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt), respectively.
3. Executed `setup.py`:

   ```
   python setup.py py2exe
   ```
4. Tested the output before using IExpress:

   ```
   dist\hello-pyqt.exe
   ```
5. Bundled it with IExpress in the usual way:

   - Added both `hello-pyqt.exe` and `library.zip`.
   - Set the *Install Command* to `hello-pyqt.exe`.
   - Enabled *Long File Name support*.

Compare your process with the one I'm using (above) and see if there's anything that might help. Failing that, I'd use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which DLL it's failing to load and where it's looking.

---

The DLLs that are bundled in my `library.zip` are: `QtCore4.dll` and `QtGui4.dll`. You might want to check your `library.zip` to make sure those files are there.