# PyQt GUI not working

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt

I am running the below code and nothing is getting displayed.

Please suggest where I am wrong.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


label = QLabel("<font color = red size = 72><b>" + "Hello" + "</b></font>")
label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
label.show()
Qtimer.singleShot(6000, app.quit)
```

I have :
python 2.7,
PyQt 4.10.4,
Qt 5.2.1 and 
MinGW 4.8

In the Environment Variables,
PATH is set as : ;C:\Qt\5.2.1\bin

Could there be some setup issue, as I installed everything and I was trying on few codes and I am facing issues.

Comment: Is this your entire program? If so, you're missing the QApplication instantiation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762870/how-to-implement-a-simple-button-in-pyqt for an example.

Comment: If I don't wish to pass any argument from the command line, then what should I enter in place of sys.argv in : QApplication(sys.argv) ?

Comment: Normally you would still pass `sys.argv` and just not give any extra command-line arguments when starting the Python process.